# Bad Magic Number in Superblock or Not a Block Device

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I'm having some real problems getting a drive to have any working partitions on it at all. The drive is a 2Tb one from a NAS that I'm trying to repair. I've written zeros to the first 77Gb of the drive (as it took an entire day!) using `dd`, thinking this would help.

Every time I try to recreate the partition table on the drive, every partition tells me that the superblock has a bad magic number. I've not even tried to format it in any way.

Whenever I try to use `mdadm` on the drive, I get told that the drive is not a block device, which led me to try and figure out what is wrong, to then discover this bad magic number issue.

I really don't know what to do with it, as all the tutorials I can find tell me to use `fsck` or `e2fsck` to repair the block, but I have no filesystem yet.

So, I guess the real issue is this 'not a block device`, but what does that even mean? It must be as it's a drive?!

Has anyone come across this weirdness before? I don't know what details to post, so if anyone needs any info, please ask for it.

Comment: Did you try to wipe the last few MB of the drive? (Sometimes information does not just get stored in the very first part of the disk, but also a reserve copy at the end. Which is truly fun when multiple schemes to to do that 'smart backup' thing.)

Comment: Hi Hennes, yes I wiped the first 32Mb of each partition that was there originally, and then wiped the partition table. No luck though, so that is what prompted me to try to wipe the drive. Still no luck :( EDIT: I just read you wrote *last* few Mb. I will try that.

Comment: also did you ever put a GPT table BACK ON ?  having wiped the first 77G of the drive would have chucked that to the far side of the galaxy...would also explain the block device and magic numbers being absent ---backup anything of value on the remaining ~1.8T FIRST THO

Comment: As it was a blank drive, I didn't care much for data loss. In a fit of annoyance, I pulled it out of my linux machine and connected it to my Mac. I formatted one large partition in OSX Journaled, then trashed that too. Adding it back to my Linux machine and it was working perfectly again.